# Android ClassNotFoundException w/ Google Maps API

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, classnotfoundexception

My Home Activity is trying to start LocationSetter MapActivity.

Here are the relevant lines of the Home Activity:

```
            try
        {
            Intent locationSetter = new Intent(Home.this, Class.forName("LocationSetter"));
            startActivity(locationSetter);
            overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e1)
        {
            Log.v(TAG, e1.toString());
        }
```

This code catches a ClassNotFoundException on the line that instantiates the class variable. 
I didn't think that using Class.forName() was necessary until LocationSetter.class started throwing exceptions, the try catch loop is just convenient because the program doesn't crash every time.

Next is the LocationSetter MapActivity:

```
package com.knox.vicinity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import com.google.android.maps.*;

public class LocationSetter extends MapActivity
{

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.locationsetter);

    MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
}

public void onBackPressed()
{
    super.onBackPressed();
    overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);
}

protected boolean isRouteDisplayed()
{
    return false;
}
}
```

I don't think there's anything wrong with this code.

I've checked whether all my activities and libraries are declared in the manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0"
package="com.knox.vicinity"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>
<uses-sdk
    android:targetSdkVersion="10" />
<uses-library
    android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"
></uses-permission>
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"
></uses-permission>
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"
></uses-permission>
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS"
></uses-permission>
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION"
></uses-permission>
<application
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:debuggable="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher_vicinity"
>
    <uses-library
        android:name="com.google.android.maps"
        android:required="true" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Splash"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
    >
        <intent-filter>
            <action
                android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category
                android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Home"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
    >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".LocationSetter"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
    ></activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

locationsetter.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.maps.MapView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/mapView"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:clickable="true"
android:apiKey="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" />
```

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong here. I have the Android project declared using Google API's Level 10 (Which includes the google maps libraries). I have no relevant warnings or errors in eclipse. I'm pretty sure my api key is correct.

Why would LocationSetter not be found?

Thanks ahead of time.

EDIT:

Stack Trace:

```
08-26 02:04:55.506: ERROR/dalvikvm(15748): Could not find class 'com.knox.vicinity.LocationSetter', referenced from method com.knox.vicinity.Home.onOptionsItemSelected

08-26 02:04:58.905: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15748): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

08-26 02:04:58.905: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15748): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.knox.vicinity.LocationSetter

08-26 02:04:58.905: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15748):     at com.knox.vicinity.Home.onOptionsItemSelected(Home.java:45)

08-26 02:04:58.905: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15748):     at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2251)

08-26 02:04:58.905: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15748):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:809)

08-26 02:04:58.905: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15748):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:143)

08-26 02:04:58.905: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15748):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:855)

08-26 02:04:58.905: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15748):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.IconMenuView.invokeItem(IconMenuView.java:553)

08-26 02:04:58.905: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15748):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.IconMenuItemView.performClick(IconMenuItemView.java:122)

08-26 02:04:58.905: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15748):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9089)

08-26 02:04:58.905: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15748):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)

08-26 02:04:58.905: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15748):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)

08-26 02:04:58.905: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15748):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)

08-26 02:04:58.905: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15748):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3806)

08-26 02:04:58.905: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15748):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

08-26 02:04:58.905: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15748):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)

08-26 02:04:58.905: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15748):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)

08-26 02:04:58.905: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15748):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)

08-26 02:04:58.905: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15748):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

08-26 02:05:06.842: ERROR/NetStatUtils(15757): The report APN is not in local map, un-match case, fatal error!!
```

Comment: Can you log the whole stacktrace (and post it here)?

Comment: are you sure you have google api in your emulator. in my app the uses-library is just before the closing tag of application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the problem was the rooted rom that was running on my Droid X. After SBF'ing my phone the program app working.

Answer (score 0):

Try `Intent locationSetter = new Intent(Home.this, LocationSetter.class);` instead

Comment: "I didn't think that using Class.forName() was necessary until LocationSetter.class started throwing exceptions"